# Run perl script while computer is locked

Tags: windows, perl, background, mode, locked

I have written a perl script which runs in the background right after a user logs in on a window xp machine. Now the script runs fine until the user is working on the computer. But if he locks the computer or the screen saver is started (which also locks the pc soon) then the script stops working. So how can I get the script running even if the Pc is in locked mode ???

Comment: Looks like he's working on some pretty dubious stuff, see also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=932396

Comment: My script takes screen shots of the current screen at random time intervals while running in background and commit the image to a server via Subversion and goes to sleep mode for some random time. It keeps on running in sleep mode when the pc is locked but at the time it wakes up for another screen shot it exits if the pc is locked.So what should I do to keep it running under any circumstances???

Answer (score 2):

Locking a computer will not stop a regular perl script, you have to go out of your way to create a script to notice when a computer is locked and stop running

Try it, run this
`perl -le " for( 1 .. 20 ) { print scalar gmtime; sleep 1; } "`
lock the computer, wait a few seconds, unlock it, and you'll see it kept running

Comment: My script takes screen shots of the current screen at random time intervals while running in background and commit the image to a server via Subversion. And it exits as soon as the computer is locked. So what should I do to keep it running under any circumstances???

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... you might have to run the perl script as a windows service to keep it running (kind of emulating Unix's nohup).